# How can I deal with the 'Any' type in hashes?

Tags: scala, hashmap

In my hash

```
val envMap = collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]()
```

I have another hash which is an array of hashes

```
val servicesArray = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]]()
envMap += "services" -> servicesArray
```

I'm trying to get into the servicesArray from the envMap

```
envMap.get("services").get.append(servicesMap)
```

but I get this error 
    error: value append is not a member of Any

Should I explicitly convert envMap.get("services").get to a list so that I can append to it, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Current return value:

```
Any = ListBuffer(Map(One -> 1, Two -> ii))
```

What I want:

```
scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]] = ListBuffer(Map(One -> 1, Two -> ii))
```

Comment: Yes you should explicitly convert envMap.get("services").get.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]]]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should declare this instead:

```
val envMap = collection.mutable.HashMap[String,ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]]]()
```

As OP mentioned, not all values are List, then you can probably do:

```
envMap.get("services").get match {
  case s:ListBuffer[[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Any]]] => s.append(serviceMap)
  case _: =>  // Or something else
}
```

You can also abstract the `"services"` out so it can be useful for all keys.

Comment: besides, you can just use `envMap("services")` instead of `envMap.get("services").get`.  If you want to guard against non-existing key, you can handle that in the `match - case` with slight modification.

Comment: I think this would still go to the wildcard case in my situation, just updated post with what I get when I run envMap.get("service‌​s").get

Comment: it should match the first, not the wildcard. 
scala> val x = Map(1->2, 3->"hello")
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> hello)
scala> x(1) match {
     | case y:Int => y + 1
     | case y:String => y + "H"
     | }
res7: Any = 3